# Reducing Consistency of $PA$

Tags: lo.logic, proof-theory, peano-arithmetic

By godel translation consistency of $PA$ is equivalent to consistency of $HA$.
I want to know any similar theorems for $PA$.

> 1.What is the minimal theory $T\subsetneq  PA$ such that the proof of $PA\vdash \bot$ can translate to a proof of $T\vdash \bot$?
>
> 2.Also can $T$ be $I\Sigma_1$ or a weaker theory?

thanks.

Comment: $\mathsf{PA}$ proves the consistency of $I\Sigma_n$ for all $n$, so it does not prove the equivalence between its own consistency and that of $I\Sigma_n$ for any $n$. Also, I don't think $\mathsf{HA}$ should really be considered a subtheory of $\mathsf{PA}$, as the logic is different.

Comment: The answer is $T=\emptyset$. PA is consistent, $T$ is consistent, and clearly it's minimal.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen: Yes, you are right that $HA$ is not subtheory of $PA$, I want to give an example.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: That's not what I mean. I want to know is there any proof that reducing consistency of $PA$ to a weaker theory, independent of whether $PA$ is consistent or not.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen: Also I don't want that $PA$ prove this equivalency, I want a proof for equivalence in meta language.

Comment: There is no such thing as "independent of whether PA is consistent or not". In the usual metatheory, PA *is* consistent, period. If that's not what you mean, you have to be more precise.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: The proof of the example I gave does not rely on consistency of $PA$ or $HA$, I want to know is there any similar theorem for $PA$ or not

Comment: I think what you might want to say is that equivalence of consistency of PA and of T is provable in, say, PA or some weaker system.

Comment: @Wojowu: Maybe it can be propose as you said.

Comment: @Erfan Khaniki. As pointed out by Emil Jeřábek and Wojowu, your question is not clearly stated, because  the answer to a great extent depends on the metatheory adopted.   The question is also vague in another aspects, namely, are PA and T in the question to be understood as being deductively closed or not. And if not, then *which axiomatization* of PA does your question refer to?

Comment: Some other vague things in the question: What is a “theory”? The given example suggests that first-order intuitionistic theories are fair game, what else is? Second, in the revised version: what does “can translate” mean?

Comment: But anyway, you can realistically expect only one of the following two answers: (1) $T=\emptyset$ if the situation trivializes as above, or (2) No such theory is minimal.

Comment: I think one of my questions is related. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/215404/what-are-key-sigma0-2-or-pi0-3-theorems I created PCA (primitive closure arithmetic) with this idea, but I am still busy with the full proof. I guess $I\Sigma_1$ won't do the job, but that is just a guess.

Comment: In addition to my previous comment, given the other questions on MO, it seems that PA is a conservative extenion over PA restricted to $\Pi_2$ sentences. This is in my opinion a remarkable result, but care should be taken, since this is not yet properly written down in a reviewed article.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek :By subtheory $T\subsetneq PA$, $T$ axiomatize by some axioms of $PA$ in language of arithmetic with classical logic as underlying logic. By translation I mean a proof theoritic argument such that construct a deduction tree for $T\vdash \bot$ from deduction tree of $PA\vdash \bot$. Also I do not mean proofs like Gentzen consistency proof for $PA$, I want to know is there any similar result exists or not.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: Why does not exists a minimal theory if the situation is not trivial?

Comment: Erfan, although I do understand what you mean, I agree with the others that your question is not proper. If you know the relative consistency of PA and T, then you can find your proof in T, by searching if it was given in PA, since you know the relative consistency, you know that search will succeed. Although, this is not what you, there is no formal argument against it. So, you question reduces to relative consistency. For that you need to specify the logic in which you must give the relative consistency.

Comment: @AliEnayat:By subtheory $T\subsetneq PA$, $T$ axiomatize by some axioms of PAPA in language of arithmetic with classical logic as underlying logic. By $PA$ I mean the usual axiomatization of it. I want to know is there any $T\subsetneq PA$ such that there exists a proof theoretic argument that construct a deduction tree for $T\vdash\bot$ from deduction tree of $PA\vdash\bot$ or not. Also I do not mean proof like Gentzen consistency proof for PAPA, I want to know is there any similar result exists or not.

Comment: Another formulation, which might be closer to what you want, is the minimal T, for which PA is conservative extension for the $\Sigma_1$ sentences.

Comment: @LucasK.: Over $\Sigma_1$ sentences of natural number or $\Sigma_1$ sentences that $PA$ proves?
Also What do you mean by relative consistency? Both $T$ and $PA$ have  classical logic as underlying logic